# Whats a good way to save tile sprites from my level editor?

Tags: java

I have built a tile based level editor in java, It is just about completed, but as I was writing the method to save the level, that all of my tiles were image sprites and I dont know of a way to save them so that the actual game can read them without making each tile it's own image file which I would then need to import to read in the real game.  (there are over 700 possible tiles, a level would probably use 100 of those);

My question to you all: what is the best way to save all these tiles? I am familiar with saving things to a text file but I am not able to save these images in the same way. Is there a way to save the level so that my text based information is saved in the same place as my tile sprites?

here is my tile class and what I have so far in terms of my save method

```
    public class Tile {
     int x, y, w, h, type;
     BufferedImage layer1Image;
     BufferedImage layer2Image;
     BufferedImage layer3Image;
     BufferedImage layer4Image;
     boolean walkable;

     public Tile(int x, int y, int w, int h) {
      walkable = false;
      this.x = x;
      this.y = y;
      this.w = w;
      this.h = h;
      type = 0;
      layer1Image = null;
      layer2Image = null;
      layer3Image = null;
      layer4Image = null;
     }

     public Tile() {

     }

     public int getX() {
      return x;
     }

     public int getY() {
      return y;
     }

     public int getW() {
      return w;
     }

     public int getH() {
      return h;
     }

     public void setX(int newX) {
      x = newX;
     }

     public void setY(int newY) {
      y = newY;
     }

     public void setW(int newW) {
      w = newW;
     }

     public void setH(int newH) {
      h = newH;
     }

     public boolean mouseOver(int mouseX, int mouseY) {
      if (mouseX > x && mouseX < x + w && mouseY > y && mouseY < y + h) {
       return true;
      }
      return false;
     }

     public int getType() {
      return type;
     }

     public boolean getWalkable() {
      return walkable;
     }

     public BufferedImage getLayer1Image() {
      return layer1Image;
     }

     public BufferedImage getLayer2Image() {
      return layer2Image;
     }

     public BufferedImage getLayer3Image() {
      return layer3Image;
     }

     public BufferedImage getLayer4Image() {
      return layer4Image;
     }

     public void clearImages() {
      layer1Image = null;
      layer2Image = null;
      layer3Image = null;
      layer4Image = null;
      walkable = true;
     }

     public void setImage(BufferedImage image, int layer) {
      switch (layer) {
      case 0:
       layer1Image = image;
       break;
      case 1:
       layer2Image = image;
       break;
      case 2:
       layer3Image = image;
      case 3:
       layer4Image = image;
      }
     }

     public void display(Graphics g, int x, int y, int w, int h, int zoom) {
      g.setColor(Color.BLACK);
      g.drawImage(layer1Image, x, y, w, h, null);
      g.drawImage(layer2Image, x, y, w, h, null);
      g.drawImage(layer3Image, x, y, w, h, null);
      g.drawImage(layer4Image, x, y, w, h, null);
      g.drawRect(x, y, w, h);

     }

     public void getAttributes(Tile tile) {
      layer1Image = tile.getLayer1Image();
      layer2Image = tile.getLayer2Image();
      layer3Image = tile.getLayer3Image();
      layer4Image = tile.getLayer4Image();
      x = tile.getX();
      y = tile.getY();
      w = tile.getW();
      h = tile.getH();
      walkable = tile.getWalkable();
      type = tile.getType();

     }

     public void setWalkable(boolean b) {
      walkable = b;
     }



          //  Here is the save, its in a different class in case my formatting in the post is screwy






        public void doSaveAsText() {
      if (fileDialog == null) {
       fileDialog = new JFileChooser();
      }
      File selectedFile;
      if (editFile == null) {
       selectedFile = new File("levelData.txt");
      } else {
       selectedFile = new File(editFile.getName());
      }
      fileDialog.setSelectedFile(selectedFile);
      fileDialog.setDialogTitle("Select File to be Saved");
      int option = fileDialog.showSaveDialog(this);
      if (option != JFileChooser.APPROVE_OPTION) {
       return;
      }
      selectedFile = fileDialog.getSelectedFile();
      if (selectedFile.exists()) {
       int response = JOptionPane.showConfirmDialog(this, "Already exists, overwrite?", "Confirm Save", JOptionPane.YES_NO_OPTION,
         JOptionPane.WARNING_MESSAGE);
       if (response != JOptionPane.YES_OPTION) {
        return;
       }

      }
      PrintWriter out;
      try{
       FileWriter stream = new FileWriter(selectedFile);
       out = new PrintWriter(stream);
      } catch (Exception e){
       JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(this, "error");
       return;
      }
      try{
       out.println("LevelEditor v1.0");
       for(int i = 0; i < mapPanel.tilesList.size(); i++){
        Tile currentTile = mapPanel.tilesList.get(i);
        out.println("startTile");
        out.println("" + currentTile.getX());
        out.println("" + currentTile.getY());
        out.println("" + currentTile.getW());
        out.println("" + currentTile.getH());
        out.println("" + currentTile.getWalkable());

        out.println("endTile");
       }
       out.close();
      }catch(Exception e){
       System.exit(0);
      }

     }



Any suggestions would be great
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could just save the whole higher in hierarchy Java objects to an output stream, and load them at a later stage.

[See this example](http://www.javadb.com/writing-objects-to-file-with-objectoutputstream).

Comment: I'm not sure how to do that, do you mean just save it with output stream instead of a printwriter?

Comment: Yes, you use the ObjectOutputStream and ObjectInputStream classes. I added a link with an example, to the answer, and also you can find an explanation with a very simple example here: http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/io/objectstreams.html

Comment: You're welcome. Would look good if you accepted the answer also by clicking the green thick at the side of the answer :D. And good luck with that ;)

Comment: I looked into the ObjectOutputStream and it turns out that buffered images cannot be serialized, am I missing something?

Comment: You can get around that problem by converting the image to another serializable object like an Array for example. There is an example of that here: http://www.devx.com/tips/Tip/5569

Comment: Thanks a lot for the help, I wrote a class to convert the buffered image into a byte array, hopefully that will work, testing it now.

Answer (score 0):

check out the serialization API, or just extract the bytes and make hexadecimal strings from them.

Answer (score 0):

How about encapulating the `BufferedImage` into a `TileImage` class that holds a reference to a particular image, then you can output the image reference in your save file. That way you don't have to save the image data over and over again, and updated graphics will be available to saved games.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if you're more concerned about the fact that your tile images are separate from your text information, or the fact that each tile image will be in a separate file from the other tiles.

For the first problem, you may be able to store your textual date in image metadata (eg: a comment). Then your tiles would just be images files.

If you're more concerned about the fact that each tile image will be in a separate file from the other tiles then you could create a single image that consists of all of your tile images in a grid (or something similar). You then have a single image file that you can also edit in standard image editing software if you desire.

Comment: As of right now the terrain editor is finished, though it is not populated with any thing but terrain (enemies, the player etc). I want to be able to save everything in the same place when it is finished (the tiles location, sprites, any event triggers, or npcs) and be able to run the game from that information that is all in the same place or easy to piece together from as few sources as possible and easily write code to run the finished level.